# How to change rule on iptables on my router?

Tags: iptables

How can I change rule on iptables on my router from

```
Chain ipfilter (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            destination IP range 10.0.0.1-10.255.255.254 
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

to

```
Chain ipfilter (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            destination IP range 10.0.0.1-10.255.255.254
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

Comment: what is the output of `iptables -S ipfilter`? What type of router do you have?

Comment: iptables v1.3.5: Unknown arg `-S', I dont have -S

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it

```
iptables -R ipfilter 2 -j ACCEPT
```